# Is there a new preferred way of scaffolding out CRUD templates in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I used to use `nifty_generators` but that hasn't been maintained in a long time. I also know that many people caution against using scaffolding, but what's the alternative? To code everything from scratch? If you code everything from scratch, doesn't it just end up looking like scaffolding?

Comment: Only if you write it identically to scaffolding.

Comment: If you try coding it from scratch, you'll probably find you end up with less than you would have with the generators, as you wouldn't add anything you don't explicitly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding is like off-the-rack clothing: fits a decent range of sizes, but isn't tailored for you.

Coding from scratch gives you more control, and lets you save time that you might have spent deleting/rewriting the scaffolded code to suit your needs. I don't think I've ever ended up with anything from-scratch that looks just like the scaffolding (and, like Zach Kemp notes above, writing from scratch means you won't add stuff unintentionally).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see an issue with scaffolding. However, I will say that I usually modify the migration to add indexes and also trim up the controller/views if certain options will not be used. If you are creating something that will need the CRUD template and the corresponding views, I would say go for scaffolding.

However, I don't always fall back onto scaffolding if I'm creating an associated object (like Emergency Contact List for User). I would just create the model and associate it to the User in a nested forms style.